# Need to make custom seekbar for music player

Tags: android, android-seekbar, android-music-player

[image]

I want to make a seekbar like the one in the figure for a music player project I'm working on. 
Searched everywhere could not find anything helpful, any help will be appreciated

Comment: did you find an answer?

Answer (score 0):

I think it would be easier to implement with [ProgressBar](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ProgressBar) with a horizontal style and not [SeekBar](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/SeekBar). I think the most simple way to implement it is to set the `android:progressDrawable` xml attribute with a drawable of the pattern above (white background and the bars - invisible).